# what is default priority in android to choose available connection?

Tags: android

I want to know .

what is the default behaviour of android device in selection of network connection.

example:-

I have my `WIFI` and `MOBILE DATA`  ON.

Which connection my device will choose by default.

if it is choosing `WIFI` / `MOBILE DATA`

So why it is choosing please explain it.

Comment: WIFI is chosen first. I would assume it's because the speed would be faster in most cases and most Data plans are limited and would rank up your bill

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a programming question.

Comment: sorry to post this non programming question.

Comment: suggest me any good theoritical forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Link which gave my answer.

which is perfect and good answer

http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/let-wifi-and-3g-connection-work-together-by-hacking-connectivityservice-java/